# Can't install shell themes

Tags: 14.04

I'm new to Ubuntu (14.04) and tried to install some fancy themes using shell extension, but I'm not able to install themes downloaded from the internet:

http://postimg.org/image/r7l8g9657/

http://s13.postimg.org/t73elw59z/Screenshot_from_2014_12_21_15_40_17.png

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Unity?

Comment: No, gnome-shell. I managed to "install" it by rebooting and creating .theme folder in my home folder but the themes don't seem to have full effect:

http://postimg.org/image/m9308m6wj/

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

you have to enable the user themes under extensions in th gnome tweak tool. (load shell themes from user directory) then copy the theme to the themes folder and you will be select the option from gnome tweak tool to install

Comment: I did it, but still have the same issue: http://postimg.org/image/4qz0wn8oj/

Also, can't accesses usr/theme folder due to permission reasons, dunno why

Answer (score 0):

Since you've enabled the user themes within the shell extension, you actually have to convert the theme files to .zip, and **not** have it as tar.gz.  This is a problem I had as well.

Once you've got the files converted to .zip, you can navigate to them through gnome-tweak-tool or whichever tool you'd like to use.  [gnome-tweak-tool apparently doesn't like those filetypes other than zip.  Bites harder than incorrect formatting in python, eh?].

Comment: It's such a late response because I just had the issue, a bit of researching and tests later, I figured it out.  Had the problem when downloading the 'dark theme'.